# Adjust size of a font in Print Preview MS Project 2010

Tags: printing, report, font-size, ms-project

Having a hard time with printing reports or anything in MS Project 2010. Font is too Small almost non existent (like little dots).  Zooming in 300% reveals that data is there bud not readable otherwise. Please help

Screen
[image: Screenshot: Report Print Preview in MS Project 2010]

Comment: Four years later, still an issue  :(

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit to figure this out and I'm on version 2016.  You need to add the Font Size control to the ribbon.  This allows you to select objects, such as a table, in the report and modify the font of the entire table.